# Loop through sheets, to delete some

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to consolidate the sheets in the workbook by deleting the ones where a cell matches. The first 10 sheets are excluded from this.

This is what I have so far:

```vb
Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 10 To WS_Count
        If Worksheets(I).Range("A13").Value = Worksheets(I + 1).Range("A13") Then
            Worksheets(I + 1).Range("A7:L9").Copy
            Worksheets(I).Range("A10").PasteSpecial
            Worksheets(I + 1).Delete
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

I get an error when this finishes running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deleting the sheets, delete in reverse else you will get an error when `I` doesn`t match the sheet number.

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim SheetsCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim scrnUpdating As Boolean
    Dim dsplyAlerts As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    With Application
        '~~> Get user's current setting
        scrnUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
        dsplyAlerts = .DisplayAlerts
        
        '~~> Set it to necessary setting
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
        
    '~~> Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
    SheetsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    
    For i = SheetsCount To 10 Step -1
        With Worksheets(i)
            If .Range("A13").Value2 = Worksheets(i - 1).Range("A13").Value2 Then
                .Range("A7:L9").Copy Worksheets(i - 1).Range("A10")
                
                .Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next i

LetsContinue:
    With Application
        '~~> Reset original settings
        .ScreenUpdating = scrnUpdating
        .DisplayAlerts = dsplyAlerts
    End With
        
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: @siddharth_Rout Thank you for this. What if I wanted to adjust it so it also checks if the sheet after matches. If so then copy the range below the previously copied range?

Comment: You tell me :)? I mean give it a try and if you get stuck, let me know and then I will share the code...